# emulate xbox controller using keyboard and mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse, emulator, game-controller, controller

So I am trying to emulate an xbox 360 controller with my keyboard and mouse. use
The OS I am using is parrotOS. As far as I can see there is not really any type of program which is able to emulate.

List of things I have tried:

[wejoy](https://github.com/Vantskruv/wejoy/) - emulates joystick instead of controller

xboxdrv, vjoypad, pyvjoy, antimicrox all require a controller or gamepad so I cannot use them as I only have keyboard and mouse

I also tried to run [Universal Control Mapper](https://github.com/Snoothy/UCR) using wine but it crashes everytime.

So, anybody has got any idea how do I emulate an xbox 360 controller on linux or getting windows is the only option?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why would you need to emulate a controller? Either you have one in which case drivers and complementary software is what you should be looking for or you set the software (games, probably) you want to run to use the actual input devices you'll be using. And no, Windows isn't an option either. This doesn't make sense irrespective of the OS. The "Xbox 360 Controller Emulator" that you can find in a cursory google search are for setting up an existing controller, not to actually "emulate" it via keyboard/mouse, i.e., software that *makes your Xbox 360 controller compatible with desktop games*.

Comment: PS - ParrotOS is a security/forensics/pentesting oriented distro. It has NOT been designed to be used as a daily driver, let alone something to "play games"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the emulator myself.
Here's the link if anyone has the same problem:
https://github.com/CommanderRag/xbox-controller-emulator-linux/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

This one also works https://github.com/iosonofabio/virtual_gamepad. You might need some python environment for running it. I.e. using [nix-shell](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Development_environment_with_nix-shell) with this `shell.nix`:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> { } }:
let
  pythonEnv = pkgs.python3.withPackages(ps: with pkgs.python3Packages; [ pynput python-uinput ]);
in
pkgs.mkShell { packages = [ pythonEnv ]; }
```